# keep exact data format when using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading csv file with pd.read_csv containing any kind of number format. All is fine, except numbers with scientific notation like -6.15000000000001E-02 are converted to float like -0.0615000000000001. Unfortunately, I need to keep the same format as in the original csv file, even the 'E' has to be kept capital.
Hope the request is clear and somebody can find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `dtype` argument. From [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) docs:

> dtypeType name or dict of column -> type, optional
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

test.csv:

```
a,b
1,-6.15000000000001E-02
```

```py
print(pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'b': str}))
```

This outputs

```
   a                      b
0  1  -6.15000000000001E-02
```

Just keep in mind that the `b` column is now a string and not a number. It will need to be explicitly converted before any attempt of doing any computation with it,

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot convert a specific column to a string, because each column (as you named as a and b) contains several numbers and I do computation with these numbers. If the computation affected the "strange" number (-6.15000000000001E-02), then I could even accept format change. But when this number is not affected by any computation, then its format must be unchanged.

Comment: @AlessandroBaiano Then I do not understand why you even care how the number is **displayed**.  Do all the computations you need, then deal with the formatting when you export the dataframe

Comment: this is a really good point. I thought to keep the format unchanged from the reading to the export, but maybe this is even impossible to have it. Then I will work on the export format

Answer (score 0):

Use dtype = str in your import could work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', dtype = str)
```